# Work from home (remotely) in the UK for an Indian company as a dependent?

Tags: united-kingdom

May I work from home remotely in the UK for an Indian company? I will have a General Tier 2 visa as a dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a dependent on a Tier 2 General visa holder, yes.

Comment: How about using VPN? will i get any issue for using other country IP? is it legal? will i question about tax evasion?

Comment: VPN is fine. No problems with the location of the VPN. If you are earning income whily normally resident in the UK, then you should be paying taxes in the UK. Check with India's tax laws for non-resident Indians to avoid getting double taxed.

Comment: My plan is to seek a job in UK while remain in the current job... once i get a job in UK then i will return and resign the current job will back to UK. May be i will be in UK for 2 month for job search, will i get any question about tax evasion?

Comment: I think you might be worrying too much about tax evasion. I seriously doubt that India or the UK will raise a lot of fuss over a month or two. Just remember that once you are resident in the UK, you pay UK taxes. Once you are non-resident of India, then follow those rules. Keep track of your dates and any supporting paperwork. You can file a self assessment your first year in the UK. The idea behind the rules of tax evasion are for people who are dishonest (or their accountants are). If you are honest and relatively accurate, you wil be fine.

Comment: I am software engineer having 7+ years of experience in Java Full stack development. How about job opening in London and Edinburgh? Is it 2 month enough to find a job?

Comment: Please give me the advice for preparation for the job search.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the stackoverflow jobs site. Good luck.